# Error in accessing the Hyperledger composer setdefault api

Tags: javascript, angular, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am using `/wallet/{name}/setDefault` api, via Angular4 application.

this.http$.post(url + `/api/wallet/${a.name}/setDefault`,{withCredentials:true}).subscribe(res => console.log(res))

I am getting this error:401 (Unauthorized).

Same way i am calling other api’s like, ping, wallet/import etc… and i am not facing this issue. Only for setdefault api.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorise your application through a third party authorization mechanism or the given Oauth 2.0 (github passport strategy) first .Then you will be authorized to make the post method.

Comment: We are using GIT hub authentication. Using that token only we are making other api calls. Only for SetDefault i am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get the X-AccessToken in the explorer?Try using it with postman .Use any extension (such as EditThisCookie in Chrome) in the browser to track if you are getting any cookie while doing `localhost:3000/auth/github`.

Another cause may be setting up of composer provider properly.
It should look like the following.

```
 export COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
    "github": {
       "provider": "github",
       "module": "passport-github",
       "clientID": "your_application_client_id",
       "clientSecret": "your_application_client_secret",
       "authPath": "/auth/github",
       "callbackURL": "/auth/github/callback",
       "successRedirect": "/",
       "failureRedirect": "/"
     }
 }'
```

And also make Content-type to null in your post message.Check with postman also.
[image]

Comment: Yes i am getting that X-AccessToken, i am using that token for other API's. Every other API is working fine. But not this. For making other calls also, i am using same, withcredetials:true, and I am not getting that auth error(401) for other API calls, only for setDefault this i am getting.

Comment: I have used this for my reference - https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc

Comment: Use the official docs,https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/introduction.html. The example with tutorial-network is easier to follow.

Comment: There is a Google OAUTH2 authentication tutorial that does exactly this. See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest  "Step 10: " onwards in particular

Comment: Great @Paul !When was it added to the doc?

Comment: @nilakanthasinghdeo in early March 2018

Comment: Great @PaulO'Mahony

Answer (score 0):

The composer-rest-server API is expecting a multipart/form-data instead of application/json as Content-Type.

I made it working by passing empty form data.

```
const formData = new FormData();
return this.http.post(this.actionUrl + 'wallet/' + encodedName + '/setDefault', formData, {withCredentials: true});
```